# Error reporting is set to 0 but it is still showing errors

Tags: php, error-reporting

In my application I have error_reporting set to 0 and just to make sure i is set when I echo error_reporting() it says it's 0.

If I leave out a semicolon on purpose just to trigger an error (somewhere under where I have it set to 0) it still displays the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in . . .

Does anyone know why this is happening? I am developing on my own machine using WAMP.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show the lines of code, that produce this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it's a parse error, it is encountered *before* it actually runs any of your code, and so it shows up.

You should change the setting in the `php.ini` file instead, as this will be handled before parsing the PHP file.

Comment: Ahh, you beat me to it. +1 for Quick fingers! =) (that and the bloody captcha trying to check if I'm a robot!!)

Comment: Thanks I get it now. I just tried to do a require() to a fake file and it didn't display the error and they are the kind of errors I am looking to hide when it's in live and testing mode.

Answer (score 0):

Parse errors are shown unless you actually set error_reporting in php.ini file to 0